# Changing EF connection string dynamically using a value provided by a jwt (.Net Core WebApi)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, .net-core

This is my first question ever so please bear with me!

I am trying to create a multi-tenant application, where a backend accesses a different database depending on a client ID obtained from a jwt which also serves to authorize API calls.

Ideally I would like to be able to access the web token in my `Startup.cs` class and generate the connection string with it. Something like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Stuff

    // get jwt claims, something like: 
    // clientId = Request.Claims["ClientId"];  However Request only seems to be accessible within a controller

    // newConnectionString = logic to replace the value found in Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default") with my desired database connection string

    services.AddDbContext<KahunaDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")));  // current state
        // options.UseSqlServer(newConnectionString));  // desired state
}
```

However, it doesn't seem to be possible to access the jwt outside of a controller.

I can't think of a way to make this happen without horribly messing up the repository pattern I have setup.

Here are some of my other classes which you might need to better understand where I am standing.

Base repository:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace API.Persistence.Repositories
{
    public class BaseRepository<TEntity> : IBaseRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
         private readonly KahunaDbContext context;
         public int ClienteId { get; set; }

         public BaseRepository(KahunaDbContext context)
         {
         }

         public void Crear(TEntity entity)
         {
              context.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
         }

         public async Task<List<TEntity>> GetTodos()
         {
              return await this.context.Set<TEntity>().ToListAsync();
         }

         public TEntity GetSingle(int id)
         {
             return this.context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
         }

         public void Borrar(TEntity entity)
         {
              this.context.Remove(entity);
         }
    }

    public interface IBaseRepository<T>
    {
        int ClienteId { get; set; }
        void Crear(T entity);
        Task<List<T>> GetTodos();
        void Borrar(T entity);
        T GetSingle(int id);
    }
}
```

Base controller:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AutoMapper;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using APIPersistence;
using API.Persistence.Repositories;

namespace API.Controllers
{
    public class BaseController<TEntity, TEntityResource> : Controller
    {
        private readonly IMapper mapper;
        private readonly IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;
        private readonly IBaseRepository<TEntity> repository;

        public BaseController(IBaseRepository<TEntity> repository, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IMapper mapper)
        {
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Authorize]
        virtual public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
        {
             List<TEntity> TEntitys = await this.repository.GetTodos();
             // List<TEntityResource> TEntityResource = this.mapper.Map<List<TEntity>, List<TEntityResource>>(TEntitys);
            return Ok(TEntitys);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] TEntityResource TEntityResource)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest(ModelState);

            TEntity tEntity = this.mapper.Map<TEntityResource, TEntity>(TEntityResource);

            this.repository.Crear(tEntity);

            await this.unitOfWork.CompleteAsync();

            return Ok(tEntity);
        }

        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id)
        {
             if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                 return BadRequest(ModelState);

             TEntity TEntity = this.repository.GetSingle(id);
             this.repository.Borrar(TEntity);
             await this.unitOfWork.CompleteAsync();

             return Ok(true);
        }

        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Put(int id, [FromBody] TEntityResource TEntityResource)
        {
             if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                 return BadRequest(ModelState);

             TEntity TEntity = this.repository.GetSingle(id);
             this.mapper.Map<TEntityResource, TEntity>(TEntityResource, TEntity);

             await this.unitOfWork.CompleteAsync();

             return Ok(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Even if you don't have time to answer the question in detail, any guidance will be extremely helpful.  Please let me know if you need any additional information.

Cheers!

Comment: Is that .net core?

Comment: Yes, let me add a tag or something